# Number of large subset.

Tags: combinatorics

We say that a subset $S$ of a finite set $U$ is large if $|S|>|U/ S|$. Here $U / S$ denotes the elements of $U$ which are not in $S$ and $|T|$ denotes number of elements in set $T$. Let $x$ be number of large subset of set $X=\{1,2,3,\cdots 10\}$ and let y be number of large subset of $Y=\{1,2,3,\cdots 9\}$ then find the value of $x$ and $y$.

My attempt: $x=2^{10}, y=2^{9}$ as number of subset having $n$ elements is $2^n$. But answer is not correct. it's given $x=386, y=256$. I'm not getting what's the point I'm missing out. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're missing out is that, if $2^n$ is the number of subsets of $X$, then it's not also the number of ***large*** subsets of $X$, unless ***all*** subsets of $X$ are large. Do you think all subsets of $X$ are large? By the way, the usual symbol for "the elements of $U$ which are not in $S$" is $U\setminus S$, not $U/S$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your definition of large, note that $S \subseteq X$ is large if and only if $X$ is a subset consisting of $6$ or more elements. Thus, we wish to know the number $x$ of subsets of $X$ that consist of $6,7,8,9,$ and $10$ elements. In other words, we wish to find

$$ x = \sum_{i=6}^{10} {10 \choose i} = 210 + 120 + 45 + 10 + 1 = 386 $$

An analogous argument can be made to solve for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer generalizes things in order to avoid adding up counts of subsets of particular sizes, but could be slower to sort out/confidently answer on an exam or similar.

A subset is large if it has strictly more elements than the complement. By pairing up subsets with their complements, this means:

- If $U$ has an odd number of elements, then half the subsets are large, so there are $2^{|U|}/2=2^{|U|-1}$ large subsets.
- If $U$ has a nonzero even number of elements, then half of the subsets which are not of middle size ($|U|/2$) are large. Therefore, there are $$\dfrac{2^{|U|}-\binom{|U|}{|U|/2}}{2}=2^{|U|-1}-\dfrac{(|U|-1)!}{\left(|U|/2\right)!\, \left(|U|/2-1\right)!}$$ large subsets.

Applying these facts to the specific sizes of $9$ and $10$ in the problem, we have the answers $2^{9-1}=2^8=256$ and $$2^{10-1}-\dfrac{(10-1)!}{\left(10/2\right)!\, \left(10/2-1\right)!}=2^9-\dfrac{9!}{5!\, 4!}$$
$$=2^{9}-\frac{9*8*7*6}{4*3*2}$$
$$=2\left(2^8-9*7\right)$$
$$=2(256-63)$$
$$=2*193=386\text{.}$$